# The program name.exe has encountered a serious problem

Tags: wine, opengl, playonlinux

I installed Wine on newly installed Linux Mint 19 Bionic edition, and also PlayOnLinux.

When I try to open a `.msi` type file with Wine Windows program loader it says: "Program error: The program warframe.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience".

What should I do? I don't know if this problem is on only this game. I also installed OpenGL 32bit libraries, which were required by PlayOnLinux, but the problem is the same.

Comment: `I don't know if this problem is on only this game.` .... run another game and find out

Comment: @Personontryingtobeuseful i tried `wine msiexec /i Warframe.msi` but then it gives me an error `0027:fixme:wtsapi:WTSQueryUserToken 1 0x69fa10`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Wine in a while, but it seems that the problem is with Wine thinking that the program is an exe, rather than an msi. I would recommend checking to make sure that Wine knows that it should expect Warframe to be an msi file.

Comment: "I would recommend checking…" – How?